# Framerate dependent movement when multiplying by deltaTime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

Why does multiplying xPos by deltaTime makes horizontal movement frame dependent, while multiplying zPos by deltaTime makes forward movement frame independent?

```
    private void Update() => Move();

    private void Move()
    {
        // Exit if movement is not allowed
        if (!allowMovement) return; 

        // Cache delta time
        float deltaTime = Time.deltaTime;

        // Set x and z postions
        float xPos = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalMoveSpeed; // * deltaTime makes horizontal movement frame dependent
        float zPos = forwardMoveSpeed * deltaTime; // * deltaTime makes forward movement frame independent

        // Add xPos and zPos to target position
        targetPosition += new Vector3(xPos, 0, zPos);

        // Clamp x position
        targetPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosition.x, leftBorder, rightBorder);

        // Move
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, deltaTime * smoothness);
    }
```

if xPos is multiplied by deltatime, the higher framerate is, the slower the horizontal movement.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow. Since `Time.deltaTime` denotes the scaled time between frames, this makes it framerate dependent. High framerate means little time between frames thus smaller values if multiplied with it. What are you trying to achieve though?

Answer (score 0):

multiplying by `Time.deltaTime` convert your movement from X units per frame to Y units per second. Because you move each frame the same amount X in first frame and it rendering took 1/30 of a second or 1/60 it still moved for amount of X.
In case of Y you would move Y * 1/30 or Y * 1/60.

This fix should help with your movement:

```
    private void Update() => Move();

    private void Move()
    {
        // Exit if movement is not allowed
        if (!allowMovement) return; 

        // Cache delta time
        float deltaTime = Time.deltaTime;

        // Calculate x and z move amount postions
        float xPos = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * horizontalMoveSpeed * deltaTime;
        float zPos = forwardMoveSpeed * deltaTime; 

        // Add xPos and zPos to target position
        targetPosition += new Vector3(xPos, 0, zPos);

        // Clamp x position
        targetPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(targetPosition.x, leftBorder, rightBorder);

        // Move
        transform.position = targetPosition;
        // More smooth version
        //transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, 0.5f);
    }
```

I thing issues that you was having are connected tho this last `Lerp` because it would set position in between current position and target position for 30 FPS it would be `currentPosition + 1/3 * ( targetPosition - currentPosition )`